# Types of Message.Content == ‘….’)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So on that blank place (….) i want the custom discord bot to read if someone mentions me on the text anywhere on the text , Possible ?

So In summary this is small code

```js
If(message.content === ‘…..’)
  {
     message.channel.send(‘the user is afk please wait’); 
  }
```

I am also thinking to add the embed type of message as a reply but thats a different thing i want to first the bot be able to read if i am getting pinged or not then will follow up

THE FULL CODE LOOKS LIKE THIS:- *idk what i am doing*

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express()

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send("Hello!")
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("The server is running!")
})

const Discord = require('discord.js')

const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    "Guilds",
    "GuildMessages",
    "MessageContent",
    "GuildMembers"
  ],
  partials: [
    Discord.Partials.Message,
    Discord.Partials.Channel,
    Discord.Partials.GuildMember,
  ],
})

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("The bot is online!!!")
})

client.on("messageCreate", message => {
  if (message.content == "test098") {
    message.channel.send("working dont disturb")
  }
  if (message.content == "embed098") {
    const embed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor('#FFFF00')
      .setTitle('The Strategy Razan is AFK')
      .setDescription('Hey there sorry i am not available, If you have queries related to it please contact the mod')
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter({ text: 'Sorry' });

    message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
  }
  })

  client.login(process.env.token)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `message.mentions.users` property, which returns a `Collection` of the users that were mentioned in the message mapped by their Discord ids.

So in your case it would look something like:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", message => {
  if (message.mentions.users.some(user => user.id === "YOUR_DISCORD_ID")) {
    // DO SOMETHING
  }
});
```

Read more about the `MessageMentions` class [here](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/discord.js/14.14.1/MessageMentions:Class)